# Динамические формы Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Необходимо реализовать задачу об очередях в виде графического интерфейса на C++.
Суть в следующем: имеются очереди в 3 различных отдела, покупатель приходит в произвольный отдел и ожидает очереди, если она не пуста. Если же очередь пуста, он делает покупки в течении определенного времени и затем выходит из очереди. Планируется создавать окно при клике на кнопке добавления нового покупателя, в этом окне будет выводится порядковый номер покупателя и его текущее состояние (ожидает, делает покупки), а при совершении покупки, окно закрывается, а покупатель удаляется из очереди. Как динамически, без щелчка мыши, показывать текущее состояние покупателя? Изначально планировалось работать с помощью `<thread>`, но, как оказалось, clr windows forms не поддерживает `<thread>`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обычный таймер используй. 3 таймера.

Comment: Если вы умеете работать с потоками, то возьмите _управляемый_ класс [Thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8) платформы .NET.